# Jest Mocked request.js Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error:

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, request, jestjs

I am trying to mock request.js to mock a file upload but it alway hangs. I have increased the waiting time but it will always timeout.

The code I am trying to mock follows the `request.post.form.append` structure. If I put the form data in manually it always fails so for functionality reasons, the functioning code cannot be modified.

I setup my require.js mock to suit only one use case which is why it is written the way it is.
My require.js mock is as follows:

```
const request = {
  post: jest.fn(() => ({
    form: jest.fn(() => ({
      append: jest.fn(test => {
        console.log(test)
        return Promise.resolve({
          status: 200,
          body: { test }
        })
      })
    }))
  }))
};

module.exports = request;
```

My jest code is as follows:

```
    it('should upload a file', async () => {
      mocks.post.mockReturnValueOnce({
        status: 200,
        body: { test: 'response' }
      });

      const res = await dataSource.uploadFile(
        { name: 'projects', id: '123' },
        null,
        {
          filename: 'test',
          encoding: '7bit',
          mimetype: 'text/plain',
          createReadStream: jest.fn
        },
         '12345'
      );
      console.log('RES', res); // never gets here
      expect(mocks.post).toBeCalledWith('testName/123/files', {
        filename: 'test',
        encoding: '7bit',
        mimetype: 'text/plain',
        createReadStream: jest.fn
      });
      expect(res).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
```

The applicable test return is as follows:

```
  console.log folder/folderName/src/files/__mocks__/request.js:5
    file

  console.log folder/folderName/src/files/__mocks__/request.js:5
    file

 FAIL  folder/folderName/src/files/__tests__/upload.spec.js (12.673s)
    uploadFile
      ✕ should upload a file (5006ms)

  ● FilesAPI › uploadFile › should upload a file

    Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error:
```

I noticed that it logs `test` within my request mock twice, so I am guessing that it is waiting for something else to properly return. What am I missing?

The code it is running works great for actual uploads, I am just struggling to write a unit test for it.

Answer (score 1):

So the timeout you specify here needs to be shorter than the default timeout.

The default timeout interval is 5 seconds if this method is not called. You can specify the timeout inside the test by adding

```
jest.setTimeout(10000); // 10 seconds
```

On official documentation explained,

> A good place to do this is in the setupTestFrameworkScriptFile. https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestsettimeouttimeout

In some cases, you only need to do setup once, and if You already have `jest.config.js` file.

```
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {

  // setup test framework after jest loaded
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [
    './tests/setupTestFrameworkScriptFile.js' // The path to a module that runs some code to configure or set up the testing framework before each test
  ],
};
```

Now we can do One-Time Setup for setTimout every test case you have,

```
// ./tests/setupTestFrameworkScriptFile.js file

jest.setTimeout(10000) // we set timeout interval is 10 seconds for every test case

beforeAll(async () => {
  await initializeDatabase(); // this is just an example
  initializeOtherDepedency();

}, 3000) // assume we only need 3 seconds for initialization before runnng test case.
```

And the last one is just your test case file

```
// uploadfile.test.js
it('should upload a file', async () => {

})
```

See also this doc:

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfilesafterenv-array

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestsettimeouttimeout

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#beforeallfn-timeout